# CSS 3 animate it no funciona en bloque de código de MVC

Tags: css3, asp.net-mvc-5, animate.css

estoy diseñando un VIEW en MVC, sin embargo al integrar el "CCS 3 animate it" me estoy dando cuando que las animaciones que están dentro de un bloque de código no funcionan, por ejemplo:

tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="animatedParent">
<img src="~/Contenido/img/Menu/Portada.jpg" class="animated bounceInLeft" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

y aquí la animación funciona perfectamente

pero, si integro la animación dentro de un bloque de código, así:

```
@foreach (var Tipo in Model.TipoProductoVw)
                        {
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <div class="animatedParent">
                                        <div class="animated fadeInUpShort">
                                            <h1 style="font-size: 48px; color: #eb7422; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: #383838 1px 2px 3px">@Tipo.Nombre</h1>
                                            @if (Tipo.Fotografia != null)
                                            {
                                                <img src="~/Contenido/img/@Tipo.Fotografia" style="width: 250px; border-radius: 100px;" />
                                                <br />
                                            }

                                            @if (Tipo.Descripcion != null)
                                            {
                                                <h5 style="font-size: 20px; text-align:center;">
                                                    @Tipo.Descripcion
                                                    <br />
                                                    @Tipo.Description
                                                </h5>
                                            }

                                            <img src="~/Contenido/img/Menu/Adorno.jpg" style="width: 250px;" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
```

Aquí la animación ya no funciona
¿Alguien tiene idea porque?

Comment: ¿Cómo has instalado la librería en tu proyecto? ¿Está en el orden adecuado?

Comment: Si, dentro de head tengo: <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Contenido/css/animate.css" /> y antes de cerrar body: <script src="~/Contenido/js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega el layout que tienes, creo que hace falta una section donde va esa llamada al js.